# Why netty uses only one thread?

Tags: java, udp, netty

I am trying to write an udp-server. I configured my bootstrap in this way:

```
ChannelFactory factory = new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    ConnectionlessBootstrap bootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(factory);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new UDPServerPipelineFactory());
    bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576*2);
    bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 1048576*2);
    bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory", new AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory(1048576, 1048576, 2000000));
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(11000));
```

Pipline in this way:

```
@Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception
{
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

    pipeline.addFirst("execution-handler", new ExecutionHandler(new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(16, 2333444, 3444333)));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("counter", new UDPHandler());

    return pipeline;
}
```

But my UDPHandler always managed only by one thread. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please add `jstack` output?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Finally I figured out that there are more than one thread. I was confused because they changed rarely and it seemed for me like onky one thread. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/netty-users/2009-September/001350.html

Today we encountered the same problem, For UDP, there is only one channel which have a worker.

So only one Thread is used. Not sure why Netty do not provide some speical factory only have one thread to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. It seems like Netty UDP only uses a single thread to process requests. There is a [issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1706) reported on this as well.

You better create a ExecutorService to execute your business logic after receiving the request.